# What would happen to the transverse nature of EM field if photon had a mass?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, lagrangian-formalism, mass, maxwell-equations

If the photon had mass, will Maxwell's equations in free space $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0$ still be satisfied? If not, will the transverse nature of EM waves (which follows from the divergence relations $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0$) still be maintained?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens for a Proca field. The corresponding "electric field" will not remain divergenceless i.e., $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\textbf{E}\neq 0$ but the corresonding "magnetic field" will remain divergenceless. Hence the transverse nature of the electromagnetic field is spoiled because of $\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{E}\neq 0$. For details, see [section 4 of this note](https://fias.uni-frankfurt.de/~poenaru/PROCA/proca_rila06.pdf).